# Going to Italy from USA with a Peruvian Passport

Tags: visas, uk, transit, paperwork, peruvian-citizens

I am Peruvian going from USA to Italy and I have to stop in London's airport, do I need a visa for a couple of hours?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [UK.GOV](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/peru/transit/somewhere_else/no) website, you do **not** need a visa to pass through the UK in transit.

This also applies [if having separate bookings](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/peru/transit/somewhere_else/yes), since you have a US visa.